# Lexical scoping in a for loop enclosing a promise?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, scope, promise, lexical-scope

I have an `ids` object, which maps `id` strings to `product` objects.

```
for id of ids
  product = ids[id]
  console.log product # Prints out something different each loop. :)
  Product.create(product).then ->
    console.log product # Only prints out the last id each loop. :(
```

I'm using a library for database interactions, which exposes promises (indicated by the `then` function above). I'm trying to print out the `product` variable inside the `then` function, but I only seem to be getting the last `id` in `ids`, so it looks like it's a scoping issue. How can I scope the `product` variable properly so that it prints out a different product in the `then` function each loop?

Comment: In this case specifically, https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b9a7ba426e1c0e6affe0.

Comment: @false Where are you getting `forEach` from?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: @false I don't have an array...

Comment: Use `Object.keys(ids)`, then.

Comment: What does `Product.create()` do, can you link the docs somehow? It seems to return a promise, but you don't seem to be interested in the resolution value? Why do you `console.log product`, but talk of the `id`?

Comment: @false: Reopening since this is a coffeescript question.

Comment: @false: But none of the answers there is in coffeescript? Since CS does have a special syntactic element for this, it matters imho.

Comment: @Bergi: CoffeeScript has a special syntax for calling a function… it’s not *too* different. But… that’s still an idiom, isn’t it? Anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@false did find the [right duplicate describing your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example). Indeed, you've got a scoping issue where `product` is non-local to the loop body, and you get the last item only from your asynchronous callbacks.

> How can I scope the product variable properly so that it prints out a different product in the then callback?

In idiomatic coffeescript, you will use the [`do` notation](http://coffeescript.org/#loops) for the IEFE in the loop:

```
for id of ids
  do (product = ids[id]) ->
    console.log product
    Product.create(product).then ->
      console.log product
```

Or, drawing the property value directly from the `of`-loop:

```
for id, product of ids
  do (product) ->
    …
```

Answer (score 2):

Bergi's code is misleading IMO since it runs the whole loop at once, not sequentially. For that reason I would just lift all the code to work in promises instead of mixing sync and async:

```
Promise.resolve(product for _, product of ids).then next = (products) ->
  [product, products...] = products
  if product
    console.log product
    Product.create(product).then ->
      console.log product
      next products
.then ->
  console.log "all done"
```

The difference is:

- Like in a real loop, next item won't run until the previous has completed
- Like in a real loop, the next line (just needs a `then ->` runs only after the loop has completed completely

These properties of a real loop are much more important than superficial syntax which you can learn in a couple of days.

Let it run and look at the difference in the logs.

Comment: I don't think OP wanted to execute them sequentially. You might of course easily run them in parallel and collect their results by `Promise.map((p for _, p of ids), Product.create)` or similar. My answer actually wasn't about the promise part, only about the closure.

Comment: @Bergi I don't think he is even aware of such difference (sequential vs parallel), I am here to enlighten